# Calling coldfusion component from java

Tags: java, coldfusion, coldfusion-8

I have a coldfusion component and I would like to call a function it from my java.

```
<cfcomponent name="coldFusionComp">
    <cffunction name="callMeFromJava" access="public" output="false">
      <cfreturn "Hello World!">
    </cffunction>
</cfcomponent>
```

Is that possible? If so, could you please give me an example?

Comment: In ColdFusion change the access to remote.  In java, call it as a web service.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the CFCProxy approach.

For more information you can read in the Adobe Docs. http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/Developing/WSe61e35da8d318518-106e125d1353e804331-7ffb.html

Comment: I am using coldfusion 8 unfortunatelly. Does it work with this version?

Comment: According to Ben Forta's [CFCProxy Post](http://www.forta.com/blog/index.cfm?mode=entry&entry=A61BD06B-3048-80A9-EF15B0E3B096BFCD), it was available in CF 7.0.1.

Another thing you can look at is the [CFC Dynamic Proxy](https://github.com/markmandel/JavaLoader/wiki/ColdFusion-Component-Dynamic-Proxy)  which is part of the JavaLoader project.  I have not used this myself.

Comment: @abbottmw is right. you can use it in CF8 also as it started way back in CF7.